# MarkLogic Error instance is not defined using instance converter module

Tags: javascript, entity, marklogic

> error: [javascript] JS-JAVASCRIPT: let instance = Completed.extract-instance-CompletedObjectives(source); -- Error running JavaScript request: ReferenceError: instance is not defined:

My Code:

```
declareUpdate();

const es = require('/MarkLogic/entity-services/entity-services.xqy'); 
const Completed = require('/es-gs/CompletedObjectiveEntity-1.0.0-conv.xqy');
for (const source of fn.collection('Objective,Accomplishments')) {
let instance = Completed.extract-instance-CompletedObjectives(source);
let uri = '/es-gs/env/'+ instance.id + '.json';
xdmp.documentInsert(uri, Completed.instanceToEnvelope(instance, "json"),{collections ['CompletedObjective-envelopes']});}
```

Is in the modules database:
`es-gs/CompletedObjectiveEntity-1.0.0-conv.xqy`

The output error is

> Stack Trace
> At line 7 column 33:
> In `let instance = Completed.extract-instance-CompletedObjectives(source);`

> 5. const Completed = require('/es-gs/CompletedObjectiveEntity-1.0.0-conv.xqy');
> 6. for (const source of fn.collection('Objective,Accomplishments')) {
> 7. **let instance = Completed.extract-instance-CompletedObjectives(source);**
> 8. let uri = '/es-gs/env/'+ instance.id + '.json';
> 9. xdmp.documentInsert(

The name of the function is
`declare function completedObjectives:extract-instance-CompletedObjectives()`

I used the instance generator to create the module:

```
const es = require('/MarkLogic/entity-services/entity-services.xqy');
const ARTIFACT_DIR = '/data/modules/';
const desc = cts.doc('/es-gs/models/CompletedObjective.entity.json');
xdmp.save(ARTIFACT_DIR + 'CompletedObjectiveEntity-1.0.0-conv.xqy', es.instanceConverterGenerate(desc));
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your collection really `Objective,Accomplishments`, or did you intend to specify an array of two collections: `fn.collection(['Objective', 'Accomplishments'])`

Comment: yes, I wanted two different collections, but it seens that I got one collection

Comment: fn.collection('Objective', 'Accomplishments')) { -- Too many args, expected 1 but got 2

Comment: I recieve the above error

Comment: you forgot the square braces, it takes an array as the parameter. Not `fn.collection('Objective', 'Accomplishments') ` but `fn.collection(['Objective', 'Accomplishments'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed line 7 in the original code above to:`let instance = Completed'extract-instance-CompletedObjectives';``

Answer (score 2):

Change line 7 of your code to:

```
let instance = Completed.extractInstanceCompletedObjectives(source);
```

When you import the Entity Services XQuery module in a JavaScript module, even though the XQuery methods have kebab-case in the source, they will be exposed and available using camelCase names:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/entity-services/getting-started#id_pgfId-1117445

> Invoke the functions using their JavaScript-style, camel-case names. For example, in the case of the Person entity type, the module converter functions can be invoked from Server-Side JavaScript using the following names, assuming the module is represented by a variable named person, as shown in the above require statement.

> - `person.extractInstancePerson`
> - `person.instanceToEnvelope`
> - `person.instanceToCanonical`

You can verify the method names exposed with camelCase by executing the following:

```
const Completed = require('/es-gs/CompletedObjectiveEntity-1.0.0-conv.xqy');
let functionNames = [];
for (const property in Completed) {
  functionNames .push(property);
}
functionNames;
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that I used the es.instanceConverterGenerate to generate the instance converter module and that is the function name that it had provided

Comment: Right, I missed that this was an XQuery Entity Services module that was being imported. Even though it is kebab-case in the XQuery module, when you use `require()` it should be visible as `extractInstanceCompletedObjectives()`. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes, I got the following result:extractInstanceCompletedObjectives

Comment: I changed line 7 to the code you suggested: I get the following error:

Comment: PlannedObjective.extractInstanceCompletedObjectives is not a function

Comment: `PlannedObjective`? I though the object was `Completed`?